# Read binary file into unsigned char vector buffer

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read a binary file stream into a `std::vector` buffer.

```
std::ifstream file(srcPath, std::ifstream::binary);
file.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
const std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(bufferSize);
file.read(buffer.data(), bufferSize);
```

But I get the following error

> Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'std::__1::basic_istream >::char_type *' (aka 'char *') with an rvalue of type 'const std::__1::vector >::value_type *' (aka 'const unsigned char *')

I'm having trouble interpreting this error and figuring out what I'm doing wrong in my call to `read`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(bufferSize);
```

You declared a `const` object here. By definition, a `const` object cannot be modified. Your plans to modify this object, by reading something into it, are already doomed to a big, abysmal, failure at this point. But there's also a second problem.

```
file.read(buffer.data(), bufferSize);
```

If you actually read your compiler's error message, slowly, it tells you exactly what the problem is.

First of all, `read()`s first parameter is a `char *`, a pointer to a character.

But you are passing a `const unsigned char *`. That's because `data()`, given that `buffer` is `const`, obviously returns a `const unsigned char *`.

And that's why you get a compilation error. If you now reread the compilation error, skipping about half of its words, it makes perfect sense now:

> Cannot initialize a parameter of type ... 'char *' with an rvalue of
>   type ... 'const unsigned char *'

To fix it, your `buffer` should ***not*** be a `const` object. Preferrably, it should be a `std::vector<char>`, so you end up really passing a `char *` to `read()`.

But, if you insist, you can keep it a vector of `unsigned char`s and use `reinterpret_cast` to cast the result of `data()` from `unsigned char *` to `char *`.

Answer (score 3):

You made your vector `const`.

So, you cannot change its contents.

You want to change its contents (that's its purpose).

So, don't make it `const`.